# In v-data-table, how I can know if I am ordering in ascending or descending inside custom-key-sort

Tags: vuejs3, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I have the necessity to customize the order in the custom-key-order to have the nulls values after the filled values, but I don't know how to get inside the function if I am ordering in ascending or descending mode.

```
const customKeySort = {
  date: (a, b) => {
    if (((a == null) || (a == '')) && ((b == null) || (b == ''))) return 0;
    if ((a == null) || (a == '')) return 1;
    if ((b == null) || (b == '')) return -1;
    return (new Date(a)).getTime() - (new Date(b)).getTime();
  }
}
```

This code works well for ascending but not in descending mode.
Could someone say me how I can get into this function what the order it should be done (ascending or descending)?

```
    <v-data-table
            :headers="headers"
            :items="items.length ? items : []"
            :search="search"
            class="elevation-1"
            :loading="loading"
            must-sort
            multi-sort
            :sort-by="[{key: 'date', order: 'asc'}]"
            :custom-key-sort="customKeySort"
     >
```

**UPDATE:**

The code corrected is:

```
    const customKeySort = {
      date: (a, b) => {
        if (((a == null) || (a == '')) && ((b == null) || (b == ''))) return 0;
        if ((a == null) || (a == '')) return 1;
        if ((b == null) || (b == '')) return -1;
        // date is in format: dd/MM/yyyy
        let d1 = a.split("/")[0];
        let m1 = a.split("/")[1];
        let y1 = a.split("/")[2];
        let d2 = b.split("/")[0];
        let m2 = b.split("/")[1];
        let y2 = b.split("/")[2];
        let a1 = (new Date(y1, m1-1, d1)).getTime();
        let b1 = (new Date(y2, m2-1, d2)).getTime();
        return Math.sign(a1 - b1);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function in custom-key-sort should behave like the compareFn passed to [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#parameters), pretty much as you do.

When sorting, v-data-table will swap arguments according to search order (see [code](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/212a8be9ae118b63562c22366d373c82f08a86f4/packages/vuetify/src/labs/VDataTable/composables/sort.ts#L127-L129)). So you don't have to worry about sort order in the comparator function.

---

Indeed, your sorter works for asc and desc when I use it in a [playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

Comment: The problem with my function is that when both A and B have values, they are being ordered in ascending mode even when should be in descending.
I don't understood what I should change looking your example code.

Comment: `- In asceding I am having (OK): 2021-03-03 | 2021-03-17 | null
- In descending I am having: null | 2021-03-03 | 2021-03-17
- But should be: null | 2021-03-17 | 2021-03-03`

Comment: It works when I put it into a playground, I have added the link to the answer

Comment: Yes, it was a conversion error from the date.
I found the error. Thanks.